# Sitecore scriban how to fetch linked item from it's linked sub item?

Tags: sxa, scriban

I have a requirement to fetch the linked item from its linked sub item along with some linked item from the parent item's field. Below is the scenario.

I have a "Landing Page"
In the "Landing Page", I have a field called "List",
In the "List" field, I have linked one page called "Main List". In the Main List page, I have a field called "childrens",
In the childrens field, I have linked few pages, I want to get these pages in my scriban along with some other items field value. Am facing difficulties getting the linked items from sub-item.

Below is the code I am trying with. Any suggestions and guidance would be thankful in advance.

```
{{
myList = i_item["List"]
$consolidatedItems = []

for eachLinkedItem in (sc_followmany i_item "Pages")
    $consolidatedItems = $consolidatedItems | array.add (eachLinkedItem)
end

$consolidatedItems = $consolidatedItems | array.add (myList["children's"])   
}}


{{$consolidatedItems | array.size}}
<br>

{{for i_item in $consolidatedItems}}
   {{i_item.path}}<br>
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - don't reuse the `i_item` variable, that should stay as the object passed in. Use a new variable name for your loop.

Next, you can just nest the `sc_follow` or `sc_followmany` to get further down the list.

```
{{for i_pageItem in $consolidatedItems}}
   {{i_pageItem.path}}<br>
   {{ for i_child in (sc_followmany i_pageItem "Childrens") }}
       <h2>{{ sc_field i_child "Title" }}</h2>
   {{ end }}
{{end}}
```

That will loop through the `$consolidatedItems` array and render the `Title` field on the target items.

You *can* do this as many times as you want, although I would advise that you should probably do something custom in your controller/repository if you have a complex set of rules regarding which items should be displayed. Try not to put too much logic in your scriban.

Comment: Thank You Richard. It solved my problem!